# Error when loading image to SQL Server database in Delphi 10.1

Tags: sql-server, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to load an image into a SQL Server database, using different code. When I tried with table insert, it shows an error message

> bitmap image is not valid

but when I try the SQL insert (jpeg error #53)

```
delphi 10.1
```

/// this code shows me the error 'bitmap image is not valid'

***// procedure created to uploading images by query***

procedure TForm3.saveimagebyQ(picname: string);
var
JP:TJPEGImage;
begin
JP:= TJPEGImage.Create;
JP.LoadFromFile(picname);
with ADOQuery1 do
begin
Parameters.ParamByName('xcode').Value:=ADOTable1Code_P.Value;
Parameters.ParamByName('xphoto').Assign(JP);
try
ExecSQL;
finally
JP.Free;
ADOTable1.Refresh;
end;
end;
end;

***//calling the procedure to use it***

procedure TForm3.Button13Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
if OpenPictureDialog1.FileName <>'' then

```
 saveimagebyQ(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
```

end;

***/// this code shows me the error 'jpeg error#53'***

Comment: Please show the actual.code you have tried, and indicate which error message goes with which code.

Comment: Please also check the formatting of the code. It would be the best to put all code into code-blocks, otherwise it is hard to read.

Comment: Which line does the exception throw from? Is it `JP.LoadFromFile(picname)`?

Comment: apparently, the problem was that delphi 10.1 berlin requires the bmb pic type and nothing else